# Abrir Popover ao carregar a página e fechar apenas pelo botão

Tags: javascript, popover

Tenho este `Popover` e gostaria que ao carregar a página ele fosse aberto, e só fechasse após o usuário clicar no `Entendi`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

o código que estou utilizando é este `Script`:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // Associa o evento do popover ao clicar no link.
            $('#Responsivo').popover({
                //trigger: 'manual',
                placement: 'bottom',
                html: true,
                title: 'O que é um site ou software responsivo?',
                content: $('#div-popover').html() // Adiciona o conteúdo da div oculta para dentro do popover.
            }).click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                // Exibe o popover.
                $(this).popover('show');
            });
    });
```

o texto da `Tag`:

```
<h4><b>Criação de Sites e Softwares <span id="Responsivo" >responsivos</span>:</b></h4>
```

e este `Modal` para o `Popover`:

```
<div id="div-popover" class="hide">
    Dizer que um site ou um software é repsonsivo, indica que ele pode ser utilizado em computadores, tablets, tvs e celulares smartphones. o conteúdo do seu site, se ajusta de acordo com a tela do disposivo.
    <br /><br />
    <button id="close" class="btn btn-primary">Entendi</button>
</div>
```

obs: para fechar tentei fazer o `script` que fizesse `hide` na `div`, mas não rolou, acredito que por que a `div`só está sendo exibida no `Popover`, então teria que fechar o `Popover`e não a `div`.

```
    $('#close').click(function () {
        $('#div-popover').hide();
    });
```

Comment: Consegue prover um Fiddle para que possamos simular?

Comment: `$('#Responsivo').popover({ .. }).popover("show");` não funciona?

Comment: @RafaelMafra funcionou para carregar sim :) valeu pela dica, sabe como faço para que feche pelo botão?

Comment: No seu evento `.click` substitua `$('#div-popover').hide();` por `$('#Responsivo').popover('hide')` ..

Comment: Não rolou pra fechar

Comment: Coloquei uma resposta, vê se funciona.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode usar o evento `show.bs.popover`

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#Responsivo').popover({
        //trigger: 'manual',
        placement: 'bottom',
        html: true,
        title: 'O que é um site ou software responsivo?',
        content: $('#div-popover').html() // Adiciona o conteúdo da div oculta para dentro do popover.
    }).popover('show');

});
```

E para fechar:

```
$(document).on('click', 'button#close', function () {
    $('#Responsivo').popover('hide');
});
```

[Exemplo](https://jsfiddle.net/5x729m9c/)

Comment: Não funcionou... ele abre se eu clicar em cima do texto `Responsivo`, e só fecha se eu clicar em cima do texto também, o botão close não fechou, e não abriu ao carregar a página

Comment: Editei o código.

Comment: Não fechou o popover

Comment: `.on('hidden.bs.popover')` realmente executa algo?

Comment: Não @RafaelMafra. Isso é evento, eu falei errado.

Comment: consegui fazendo assim: `button id="close" onclick="$('#Responsivo').popover('hide')" class="btn btn-primary">Entendi</button>` adicionando o evento diretamente no botão... Valeu pela ajuda

Comment: Que nojeira, mano. Faz no JS que é mais limpo e bonito. Faz o mais certo.

Comment: na vdd eu fiz pra testar.. pois notei que não estava chamando o evento quando clicava no botão. eu coloquei um alert pra ver se ia ser executado, e não executou

Comment: Provavelmente você esta colocando o `$('#Responsivo').click()` fora do `$(document).ready()`

Comment: Já arrumei o código, mano. Está certo agora. Postei até exemplo no Fiddle.

Answer (score 2):

Basta adicionar um `.popover('show')` na criação do popup.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Associa o evento do popover ao clicar no link.
    $('#Responsivo').popover({
        //trigger: 'manual',
        placement: 'bottom',
        html: true,
        title: 'O que é um site ou software responsivo?',
        content: $('#div-popover').html() // Adiciona o conteúdo da div oculta para dentro do popover.
    }).click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // Exibe o popover.
        $(this).popover('show');
    }).popover('show');
});
```

Para fechar a partir do botão..

```
$('#close').click(function() {
    $('#Responsivo').popover('hide');
});
```

Comment: o popover não fechou

Comment: Qual é esse plugin que você está usando?

Comment: sou meio novato ainda na programação, como verifico?

Comment: consegui fazendo assim ´button id="close" onclick="$('#Responsivo').popover('hide')" class="btn btn-primary">Entendi</button>´ colocando o evento diretamente no botão